# How to join a Windows PC to a Ubuntu domain

Tags: samba

I am running Ubuntu Server 14.04.  I have tried numerous Samba config files with no success in having Windows 7 & 8 machines join the Samba domain.  Using the **Official Samba 3 HowTo Guide**, page 49, I stripped my `smb.conf` file to bare bones.

Here is my smb.conf file content.

```
# Global parameters
[global]
    netbios name = FRANK-N-STEIN
    workgroup = TUX-NET
##  passdb backend = tbdsam
#   os level = 33
#   preferred master = yes
#   local master = yes
    domain master = yes
    security = user
    domain logons = yes
#   logon path = \\%N\profiles\%u
```

When I try to join from Windows, I get this message: "The specified domain either does not exist or could not be contacted."

However, I searched the web and discovered a Windows built-in procedure which locates domain controllers on a local network.

To use it:

1. Open Windows terminal screen
2. (2) Change directory to Users\Administrator "cd
   C:\Users\Administrator
3. Enter at the command prompt `nltest /dcname:{name of domain}`

On my Windows machines, they quickly find my domain controller, "FRANK-N-STEIN".

Can someone help me?  The nltest utility finds the domain controller but the Widows connect to a domain function can't seem to find it.  I really need to get a basic domain in operation using Ubuntu server 14.04.

Answer (score 1):

For an NT4 domain run by Samba 3 you need to specify:

```
security = domain
```

And create a UNIX user so you can login using it from Windows.

In the other hand, you need to use Samba 4 so your Windows 7 and Windows 8 computers can join an Active Directory Domain Controller run by Samba.

Here is the howto: http://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Samba_AD_DC_HOWTO